# In jointjs, how can I restrict the number of connections to each input to just one?

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I'm using jointjs and, as the question states, I need to limit the number of allowable connections to each input to a maximum of one. If an input has already been connected to by an output, then it should not allow any additional connection attempts until the existing connection is either changed or deleted.

I figure that I need to modify the validateConnection function so I'm wondering if there is a way to check the magnetT variable for an existing connection? Something like

```
if(magnetT.connected) return false;
```

perhaps by passing a custom attribute to the port upon linking.

```
on.link(){
target.connected = true;
}
```

or something to that nature. Obviously the above is pseudocode so if there are suggestions on a different way to resolved this problem, I'm all ears. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5):

You are right that validateConnection function is called when you draw a link to determine if a connection can be made to the target or not. In this function you can do whatever that you want.
Another function that is useful is validateMagnet which determine if a wire can be drawn or not when the user clicks on a magnet.

I don't think that jointJS has an API to get the links connected to an element or port. What you can do is to get all links in paper, check if the source or target of any link is connected to magnetT. If one is connected, return false.

Here is the code:

```
validateMagnet: function(cellView, magnet){
    var links = graph.getLinks();
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
        if( (( cellView.model.id  == links[i].get('source').id ) && ( magnet.getAttribute('port') == links[i].get('source').port) )||
        (( cellView.model.id  == links[i].get('target').id ) && ( magnet.getAttribute('port') == links[i].get('target').port) ))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
},
validateConnection: function(cellViewS, magnetS, cellViewT, magnetT, end, linkView){
    var links = graph.getLinks();
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    {  
        if(linkView == links[i].findView(paper)) //Skip the wire the user is drawing
        continue;

        if ( (( cellViewT.model.id  == links[i].get('source').id ) && ( magnetT.getAttribute('port') == links[i].get('source').port)) ||
        (( cellViewT.model.id  == links[i].get('target').id ) && ( magnetT.getAttribute('port') == links[i].get('target').port)) ){
            return false;
        }
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi @IsalamAbdalla it's only working for outbound port, can you give any example fiddle,that incoming link of port also accepts only one link. Thanks in Advance!